# reload parent window from within an iframe

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

I have my login page in an iframe and wished to reload the parent window using ajax and jquery from within iframe without refreshing but i'm getting errors like this

```
(this[0].ownerDocument || this[0]).createDocumentFragment is not a function
```

please help!

Comment: var u = document.referrer;
  top.window.location.href = u;

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I could achieve this by reloading the page using javascript

```
parent.location.reload();
```

then i fired a trigger to open the target iframe

```
$("#log-inout").trigger("click");
```

I needed such system for a peculiar condition. This might help others in similar conditions.

Comment: This works only if you load both windows from the same location. Otherwise, the browser refuses to reload as it is violation of "Same Origin Policy". The same applies to parent.location.href answer by Bert-Jan.

Answer (score 29):

```
parent.location.href=parent.location.href
```

gives a smoother result than

```
parent.location.reload()
```

the latter forces a complete reload while the first seems to update more effectively almost like ajax.

Comment: You can't do it if the parent domain is different with iframe domain in this way. "Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Comment: `parent.location.href=parent.location.href` Didn't work for me. the parent window did nothing.

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
window.parent.location.href = "Create?Param=value";
```

Or:

```
window.parent.location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

dont bother! why use iframes at all if you are using ajax.

just load the login using

$("where you want to load the content here").load("src of your iframe here");

```
//load via ajax
$("div").load("login.php");
```

much simpler and alot more elegant.

Comment: i actually wanted to refresh contents(parentwindow) after a user is logged in while the iframe(login) is still on

Comment: interesting idea, worth noting!

Answer (score 1):

If your iFrame and the main window are exact same domain and port, then you can use

```
window.top.location.reload()
```

Answer (score -1):

If trying all of the suggestions made you encounter a violation of "Same Origin Policy" error. You can try this solution instead:

```
window.parent.location = "URL_OF_PARENT_TO_BE_REFRESHED";
```

This is quite a brute force approach but if you guys really need a solution, I can offer this.