# Reload parent iframe from child popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe, popup

I have one page say display.aspx that is being used in other sites in Iframe. In display.aspx page, I have one button which opens Facebook popup for sharing. After successful share it gives me response in one page in my site say FBResponse.aspx. From FBResponse.aspx,I want to reload the display.aspx page.

I have tried
 `1) window.opener.history.go(0);`
             `2) window.opener.location.reload(false);`
         `3) opener.location.reload(false);`

But none of these working for me.

Moreover, I have made one function in display.aspx page, in that function I have written code to reload the page. I tried to call this function from FBResponse.aspx ,but in Chrome I am getting error **The frame requesting access has a protocol of 'https', the frame being accessed has a protocol of 'http'. Protocols must match** and in FF I am getting error **Permission denied to access property in IFRAME**. Actually my site is working on https where as the sites which are using my page display.aspx might be using http protocol.

Any solution?

Thanks,
Priya

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try This one.

```
<form onsubmit="window.top.location.href = 'http://www.wesite.com/test.html';">
```

Be attention iframe and top must be on same domain and don't break same origin policy.

Hope it would helps you.

Comment: Try this `parent.location.reload();` also refer these links [Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351342/reload-parent-window-from-within-an-iframe) [Link2](http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2008/03/28/refresh-main-parent-window-of-iframe/).Hope it would be fine for you. Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless both page and iframe have same domain (and in this case you can make protocols to match). Same origin policy can be a biatch.

Comment: The page that is being used in Iframe(display.aspx) and the page(fbresponse.aspx) from which I want to reload the display.aspx,both are having same domain. But display.aspx is used in different site than mine. Would it affect?

Comment: If they are on the same domain and you use the same domain to access them then you should be able to do what you need. Theoretically at least :).