# Reloading parent window with a button in the iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, form-submit

I have an iframe in a page like

```
<iframe src="something.html"></iframe>
```

and in the *something.html* page, I have a form and a button.

```
<form action="anywhere.html">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

When I click on the submit button, it only reloads the page *anywhere.html*  (inside the iframe). But I want *anywhere.html* to load in the same main window (not in a new tab or window or not in the iframe). How can this be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reload parent window from within an iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351342/reload-parent-window-from-within-an-iframe)

Comment: Duplicate question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954454/how-to-reload-main-page-from-within-an-iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [*target*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) attribute for the [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target) tag. Set it to *_parent* to have the form submit to the parent window (outside the frame).

> - **_parent**: Load the response into the HTML 4 frameset parent of the current frame, or HTML5 parent browsing context of the current one. If there is no parent, this option behaves the same way as **_self**.<sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target)</sup>

```
<form action="anywhere.html" target="_parent">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

See it demonstrated in [this plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/8SHg49EWG0Hj93bkxZ7L/).

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-target</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. I was searching for this answer. It really helped.